# Firebase cloud messaging in android application only working for notifications and not data messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using firebase to send push notification to android device.

```
<service
     android:name=".util.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
     android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
     </intent-filter>
</service>


class MyFirebaseMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService()  {

    private val TAG = "FirebaseMessaging"

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        Log.d(TAG, token)
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

        if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.notification!!.body)
        }
    }
}
```

I can receive notifications of a message by using postman.

```
{
    "registration_ids": ["KEY_HERE"],
    "notification": {
        "title": "HIMAN",
        "body": "werwkejh"
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, I can add a break-point and the notification comes through. However, I need this to be a data type push notification because it doesn't trigger the onMessageReceived callback when the app is in the background - only foreground. It says it's successful too in postman.

```
{
    "multicast_id": 863107467701827657,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "MESSAGE_ID"
        }
    ]
}
```

The request body for the data push notification is as follows:

```
{
    "registration_ids": ["KEY_HERE"],
    "data":{
        "message": "hi!"
    }
}
```

It's just not triggering onMessageReceived which I need. Anybody can help?

Comment: Does it work when app is in foreground?

Comment: No not for the data one, but for notification it works

Comment: If you use `data` it should work regardless if background or foreground, add a log inside onmessagerecieved to check

Comment: I did that... and i switched to data doesn't work

Comment: Anyway something weird happened recently where notification all of a sudden doesn't work. probably firebase acting up or something because I used to be able to receive notifications with notification (never data), and I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  your notification contain `"notification":` it will show notification but when app is not running then `onMessageReceived` will not call. for that case you have pass data in `"data":` field and remove `notification":` from you response.

Your response must be look like this

```
{
"to": "your device token",
 "data":{
   "name": "John",
    "message": "Hii! "
    }
 }
```

I had  same issue this worked for me.

Comment: I think your misunderstanding what I'm saying, I'm saying that when its data it doesn't work for me. only notification works for me

Comment: Use `"data":` response and  replace your `remoteMessage.notification` with `remoteMessage.data` in your `onMessageReceived` method and tell me if it is working or not?

Comment: That's a great point. I didnt realize that. Strangely enough, my notification isnt working either right now. Suddenly stopped working like a few moments ago.

Answer (score 1):

> when application close system will handle notification if notification
>   payload have notification key that will auto display notification
>   based on that. below payload display notification title and body when
>   app close and if you handle data json it will not show until app
>   started.

```
{
    "to":"some_device_token"
    "notification": {
        "title": "HIMAN",
        "body": "werwkejh"
    },"data": {
           "extra":"juice"
}
}
```

> Solution for this problem is to remove notification from payload that
>   will allow application to handle the json.

```
{
"to":"some_device_token"
"data": {
"extra":"juice"
}
}
```

**

> if payload contain notification key system will handle when app close,
>   if payload not contain notification key application will handle it.

**